# How to access session in partial page in asp.net core razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When I login into the application then I stored my UserName in the session, But I can't access it on my partial page. I'm trying to show my login credential (UserName) on the razor partial page. What can I do?

```
AppUser user = m_UserSecurity.AuthenticateUserCredentials(UserLogin.LoginID, UserLogin.Password);
HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", user.Name);
```

Comment: I am not sure what it is called, but there is a persistent class across all the pages that the razor view maintains. This is usually where data that is needed across all pages is maintained. Have you tried adding this variable there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code at your razor partial view.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext
@{
    var userName = _httpContext.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");
}

<div>
        My userName is : @userName
</div>
```

Comment: btw: Don't forget to register HttpContextAccessor in your program.cs

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

Answer (score 1):

The first method is to use  `ViewData[xxx]`, For example, After you setting session in your login action, You want to show the value of session in partial view in `Privacy.cshtml`, You can get that session in `onGet()` of `PrivacyModel`, Then use `ViewData["xxx"]` to save that value, Finally use  `@ViewData["xxx"]` to get that value in your partial view.

But but I don't recommend this method, In you case, View Component is
more suitable for you. Because View component has a "backend", you can use httpcontext to get the session in its "backend" directly. Please refer to this simple demo:

```
 public class UserViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
       //inject httpcontext to get the session.
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
        public UserViewComponent(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
        {
            _httpContext = httpContext;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            var username = _httpContext.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserName");
            return View("index",username);
        }

    }
```

**View**

Path: Pages\Shared\Components\User\Index.cshtml

```
@model string 

<h1>This is my view component</h1>
<h1>@Model</h1>
```

Then use this view component in your page

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("User");
```

[image]

**btw**: Don't forget to register `HttpContextAccessor` in your program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```